# User input validation is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a component in my ReactNative app in which user can give only numbers as input, but my JavaScript reg expression is not working correctly. I used React Native hooks to manage states. I am trying to validate user input for only numbers, but input text field also replacing the numbers with empty string. The code of the component is follwoing;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Card from '../components/Card';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import Input from '../components/Input';


const StartGameScreen = props => {

  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState ('');

  const numberInputHandler = inputText => {
    setEnteredValue (inputText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Start a New Game</Text>
      <Card style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text>Select a Number</Text>
        <Input style={styles.inputText} 
        blurOnSubmit 
        auotCaptalize={'none'} 
        autoCorrect={false} 
        maxLength={2} 
        keyboardType={'number-pad'}
        onChnageText={numberInputHandler}
        value={enteredValue}
        />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} style={{backgroundColor: Colors.accent, ...styles.button}}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Reset</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.4} style={{backgroundColor: Colors.primary, ...styles.button}}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Confirm</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 35,
    width: 80
  },
  buttonText: {
    color: 'white'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginVertical: 10
  },
  inputContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 120,
    maxWidth: '80%'
  },
  inputText: {
    width: 35,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    height: 30,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export default StartGameScreen;
```

The code for the input component is following;

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Input = props => {
    return (
        <TextInput {...props} style={{...styles.input, ...props.style}}/>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        height: 30,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        marginVertical: 10
    }
});

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled the prop in your implementation of `Input` on your `StartGameScreen` component which is responsible for handling the change.

`onChnageText` should be `onChangeText`

The reason your non numbers are "replaced" as well is actually because the change handler isn't mapped to `onChangeText` due to that typo.

**Extra Note:**

You've also made another typo in your `Input` implementation.

`auotCaptalize` should be `autoCapitalize`

Answer (score 0):

There are two spelling errors:

`auotCaptalize={'none'}` should be `autoCapitalize={'none'}`, and `onChnageText={numberInputHandler}` should be `onChangeText={numberInputHandler}`